# Riemannian and Weyl tensors as spinor representation

Tags: general-relativity, special-relativity, tensor-calculus, group-theory, spinors

There is the way of converting vector indices to spinor indices, for example, **Maxwell stress tensor** $F_{[\mu\nu]}$ can be decomposed to $(1,0) \oplus (0,1)$ irreducible representations of $\mathfrak{su}(2)_L\times \mathfrak{su}(2)_R$:

\begin{equation}
  F_{[\mu\nu]} \sim (\sigma_{[\mu\nu]})^{\alpha\beta} F_{(\alpha\beta)} + (\sigma_{[\mu\nu]})^{\dot{\alpha}\dot{\beta}} F_{(\dot{\alpha}\dot{\beta})} 
\end{equation}

Let's consider the **Riemannian tensor** $R_{[\mu\nu]\vert[\rho\sigma]}$:

\begin{equation}
  R_{[\mu\nu][\rho\sigma]} \sim (\sigma_{[\mu\nu]})^{\alpha\beta} (\sigma_{[\rho\sigma]})^{\gamma\delta} R_{(\alpha\beta)(\gamma\delta)}
+
(\sigma_{[\mu\nu]})^{\dot{\alpha}\dot{\beta}} (\sigma_{[\rho\sigma]})^{\dot{\gamma}\dot{\delta}} R_{(\dot{\alpha}\dot{\beta})(\dot{\gamma}\dot{\delta})}
\end{equation}

But objects $R_{(\alpha\beta)(\gamma\delta)}$  and $R_{(\dot{\alpha}\dot{\beta})(\dot{\gamma}\dot{\delta})}$ are reducible representations of $\mathfrak{su}(2)_L\times \mathfrak{su}(2)_R$. So we need decompose such objects further.

**How do you decompose $R_{(\alpha\beta)(\gamma\delta)}$?** What is meaning of the obtained objects ( objects like $W_{(\alpha\beta\gamma\delta)}$, $R_{(\alpha\beta)}$, $R$)?

Comment: There are two books by Moshe Carmeli on this...

Comment: @DanielC could you please provide concrete reference?

Comment: Try M.Carmeli - „Group Theory and General Relativity”, Chapter 8.

Answer (score 2):

Calculation for Ricci scalar R in terms of $\Lambda$ (notations and identities borrowed from R.Penrose (1984)):

The Infeld - van der Waerden symbols are defined as:
$${g_a}^{AA'}={g_a}^{\textbf{a}}{\epsilon_{\textbf{A}}}^{A}{\epsilon_{\textbf{A}'}}^{A'}$$ and it satisfies the following identities:

(1)$g_{ab}=\epsilon_{AB}\epsilon_{A'B'}{g_a}^{AA'}{g_b}^{BB'}$

(2i)${g_a}^{AA'}{g_{AA'}}^b={g_a}^b$ and (2ii) ${g_{AA'}}^a{g_a}^{BB'}={\epsilon_A}^B{\epsilon_{A'}}^{B'}$

(3)The "Clifford relation" :$2{{g_{(a|}}^A}_{A'}{g_{|b)B}}^{B'}=-{\epsilon_B}^Ag_{ab}$

And finally the transformation rule for spinor to spacetime indices given by:  ${\chi_{a...c}}^{d...f}={\chi_{AA'...CC'}}^{DD'...FF'}{g_a}^{AA'}...{g_c}^{CC'}{g_{DD'}}^d...{g_{FF'}}^f$

Now refer to the relation (4.6.20) from the reference: $R_{ABA'B'}=6\Lambda\epsilon_{AB}\epsilon_{A'B'}-2\Phi_{ABA'B'}$
We have  Ricci tensor given by $$R_{cd}=R_{(cd)}=R_{ABA'B'}{g_{(c}}^{AA'}{g_{d)}}^{BB'}$$ From relation (1) I can write $R_{ABA'B'}=6\Lambda g_{ab}{g_{AA'}}^a{g_{BB'}}^b-2\Phi_{ABA'B'}$, So

$R_{cd}=6\Lambda g_{ab}{g_{(c}}^{AA'}{g_{d)}}^{BB'}{g_{AA'}}^a{g_{BB'}}^b-2\Phi_{ABA'B'}{g_{(c}}^{AA'}{g_{d)}}^{BB'}$

By applying (2i) we get $R_{cd}=6\Lambda g_{ab}{g_{(c}}^a{g_{d)}}^b-2\Phi_{(cd)}=6\Lambda g_{cd}-2\Phi_{cd}$. Now contract with $g^{cd}$ on both sides. Since ${\Phi_a}^a=0$ we get $R=24\Lambda$

EDIT(1):Given the identity ${g^a}_{AA'}g^{bA'B}=g^{ab}{\delta_A}^B-i{{\sigma^{ab}}_A}^B $ verify that ${\sigma^{[ab]}}_{AB}=i{g^{[a}}_{AA'}{g^{b]A'}}_B$. Now $$R_{abcd}=R_{[ab][cd]}=R_{AA'BB'CC'DD'}{g_{[a}}^{AA'}{g_{b]}}^{BB'}{g_{[c}}^{CC'}{g_{d]}}^{DD'}$$ Expanding Riemann curvature spinor in terms of Weyl and Ricci Spinor and $\Lambda$ we will get the following expression:
$$R_{abcd}=-\Psi_{ABCD}{\sigma_{[ab]}}^{AB}{\sigma_{[cd]}}^{CD}-\Phi_{ABC'D'}{\sigma_{[ab]}}^{AB}{\bar{\sigma}_{[cd]}}^{C'D'}+c.c.+2\Lambda (g_{ac}g_{bd}-g_{ad}g_{bc})$$ Note the anti-symmetrization in space-time indices in sigma matrix. If we focus on the $\Lambda$ part, we see that on contraction with $g^{bd}$ we get back the familiar $6\Lambda g_{ac}$ term as in (4.6.20)

Comment: Where are mistakes in my answer?

Comment: I think that there are differences in defenitions 1,2,3

Comment: @Nikita I just copied those expressions (1,2,3) from the textbook "Spinors and Space-time" Volume I. Can you re-send your calculation for R and $\Lambda$? The mistake isn't actually clear from your previous answer :( Ok , just tell what is the definition for sigma matrix you used in your calculation? I will  compare those with Infeld van der Waerden symbols. That would help at least.

Answer (score 1):

The most useful reference is ch. 13 of [GR by Wald](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/General_Relativity_(book)). But in book there are some mistakes in numerical coefficients.

Expansion of Rimannian thensor:

\begin{equation}
 R_{\alpha\dot{\alpha}\beta\dot{\beta}\gamma\dot{\gamma}\delta\dot{\delta}}
 =
 \Psi_{( \alpha\beta\gamma\delta)} \epsilon_{\dot{\alpha}\dot{\beta}} 
 \epsilon_{\dot{\gamma}\dot{\delta}} 
 +
 \Phi_{(\dot{\alpha}\dot{\beta})(\gamma\delta)}
 \epsilon_{\alpha\beta}  \epsilon_{\dot{\gamma}\dot{\delta}}
 +
 \Lambda (\epsilon_{\alpha\gamma}\epsilon_{\beta\delta} + \epsilon_{\beta\gamma}\epsilon_{\alpha\delta})
 \epsilon_{\dot{\alpha}\dot{\beta}} 
 \epsilon_{\dot{\gamma}\dot{\delta}} 
 +
 c.c.
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
 16 \, R_{abcd}
 =
 - \Psi_{( \alpha\beta\gamma\delta)} (\sigma_{ab})^{\alpha\beta} (\sigma_{cd})^{\gamma\delta} 
 +
 \Phi_{(\dot{\alpha}\dot{\beta})(\gamma\delta)} (\sigma_{ab})^{\alpha\beta} (\tilde{\sigma}_{cd})^{\dot{\gamma}\dot{\delta}}
 -4 \Lambda (\eta_{a
 d} \eta_{bc} - \eta_{ac} \eta_{bd} - i \epsilon_{abcd})   +
c.c.
\end{equation}

$$
16 R = -4 \Lambda g^{ac}g^{bd} (\eta_{a
 d} \eta_{bc} - \eta_{ac} \eta_{bd}) = -4 \Lambda (4-16) = 48 \Lambda 
\;\;\;
\Rightarrow
\;\;\; \Lambda = \frac{R}{3}
$$

\begin{equation}
 \sigma^{ab}_{\alpha\beta} \sigma^{cd}_{\gamma\delta} R_{abcd}
 =
 - \Psi_{( \alpha\beta\gamma\delta)}
 +
 4 \Lambda \epsilon_{(\alpha\gamma} \epsilon_{\beta)\delta}
 +
 c.c.
\end{equation}

Comment: You can also find a detailed derivation of this decomposition in "Spinors and Space-time", Volume-I , by Roger Penrose, Wolfgang Rindler.

Comment: Btw, isn't $\Lambda=R/24$ ?

Comment: @KP99 I edited answer. I don't know, how Penrose obtain $R/24$. Maybe he used nonstandart sigma-matrices.

Comment: OK, I will redo that calculation, but since this is just a relation between scalars $\Lambda$ and R, I don't think it should depend on choice of sigma matrix. Also I found this same relation R/24 in other literatures. Anyway, let's see

Comment: Please check your calculation in the second line: You shouldn't get $16R_{abcd}=.....-4\Lambda(...)$, instead it should be $R_{abcd}=...-2\Lambda(...)$. For confirmation: see the tensor decomposition of $R_{abcd}$ in 4 dimension, it will have a term containing $R/12g_{abcd}$, but your calculation shows  $R/3g_{abcd}$

Comment: @KP99 It is very hard to discuss this here without possiblity to show concrete identities:( I have independent nontrivial check of correction of these formulas, so I think that there are differences in detentions..

Comment: I don't know if it is possible to share my roughworks by some other means. In chapter 13 Wald mentions the sigma matrix $\sigma^a_{AA'}$ which is same as van der Waerden symbols $g^a_{AA'}$ expressed in Minkowski coordinates. How is $\sigma^{ab}_{\alpha\beta}$  related to the original sigma matrix $\sigma^a_{AA'}$ ? You have used it in your calculation but I couldn't find it in the original text. I think this will solve the apparent confusion

Comment: @KP99 $\sigma^m_{\alpha\dot{\alpha}} (\sigma^n)^{\dot{\alpha}\beta} = \eta^{mn}\delta_\alpha^\beta - i (\sigma^{mn})_\alpha^\beta$

Comment: I hope the confusion is clear now

Comment: @KP99, could you explain me?

Comment: Ok, from the relation b/w $\sigma$ and g matrix you mentioned in your previous comment, see that if you take anti-symmetrization [..] in m,n indices, you will get the relation $\sigma^{[mn]}_{AB}=ig^{[m}_{AA'}g^{n]A'}_B$. Now look at Riemann spinor decomposition: (1) the Weyl spinors are associated to two $\epsilon$ spinors. $g_{[a}^{AA'}g_{b]}^{BB'}\epsilon_{A'B'}=-g_{[a}^{AA'}g_{b]A'}^B=i\sigma_{[ab]}^{AB}$. Hence you get two such sigma matrix attached to Weyl spinor part and it's compex conjugates. Same calculations also follows for Ricci spinor $\Phi$.

Comment: For $\Lambda$ part note that you can use the identity (I am using e for $\epsilon$): $e_{A'B'}e_{C'D'}+e_{A'D'}e_{B'C'}-e_{A'C'}e_{B'D'}=0$ to convert $\Lambda(e_{AC}e_{BD}+e_{AD}e_{BC})e_{A'B'}e_{C'D'}+cc$ to $2\Lambda(e_{AC}e_{BD}e_{A'C'}e_{B'D'}-e_{AD}e_{BC}e_{A'D'}e_{B'C'})$. Now you have to contract with the g matrices $g^{AA'}_{[a}g^{BB'}_{b]}g^{CC'}_{[c}g^{DD'}_{d]}$, ok?

Comment: You should get $2\Lambda(g_{[a}^{AA'}g_{b]DD'}g_{AA'[c}g_{d]}^{DD'}-g_{D[a}^{A'}g_{b]}^{B'}_Cg_{B'[b}^Cg_{d]}^D_{A'})$ .... You can now expand the anti-symmetrisation [...] in a,b,c,d indices in these g matrices and then make use of identities (1),(2i),(2ii) mentioned in my answer to get a simpler expression in metric only: $2\Lambda(g_{ac}g_{bd}-g_{ad}g_{bc})$.. this part you have to try it yourself

Comment: For some reason I can't edit the above long equation